# Exception in Meteor UI: Error: Illegal HTML attribute name: \

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm making a Meteor JS app and I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in Meteor UI: Error: Illegal HTML attribute name: \
    at extendAttrs (http://localhost:3000/packages/htmljs.js?a0a9082010d25b3fb44e0f56bdd0a7b4e6bbeb93:322:13)
    at Object.HTML.evaluateAttributes (http://localhost:3000/packages/htmljs.js?a0a9082010d25b3fb44e0f56bdd0a7b4e6bbeb93:340:3)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:2536:28
    at _assign._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:228:38)
    at new Deps.Computation (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:160:10)
    at Object._assign.autorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:380:13)
    at materialize (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:2529:27)
    at materialize (http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:2476:7)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/ui.js?9419ac08328918a04e7a49464a988d45f851e1b0:2393:7
    at Object._assign.nonreactive (http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?4a82362ae66e863a1c1a8b0a5fec6f665e2038d1:400:14)
```

It occurs when I load a page called dialogueIndex which lists links to the edit pages for elements in the `Dialogues` collection.  Here's the code:

```
client/views/dialogue_index.html
================================
<template name="dialogueIndex">
  <main>
    <h1>Dialogues</h1>

    {{#each dialogues}}
    <a href="{{pathFor 'editDialogue'}}">Edit</a> - {{summary}} - "{{text}}"
    <br \>
    {{/each}}
  </main>
</template>


client/js/dialogue_index.js
===========================
Template.dialogueIndex.helpers({
  dialogues:  function() {
                return Dialogues.find({});
              }
});


lib/routes.js
=============
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.map( function() {
  ...
  this.route('dialogueIndex',     
    {
      waitOn:   function() { return Meteor.subscribe("dialogues"); },
      path: 'dialogue/index'
    });
  this.route('editDialogue',      
    {
      path:     'dialogue/edit/:_id',
      data:     function() { return Dialogues.findOne(this.params._id); }
    });
});
```

I've been puzzling over this for a while, but I have no idea what's going on here.  Tried searching for answers, but I haven't found very much about this error.  Any help you could offer would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  `<br \>` with `<br>`.

**Side note:**
If you add `<br\>` then error thrown by Meteor is much more precise:

```
Expected "br\" end tag
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I feel so stupid.  Thanks a lot! I was beating my head against the wall on that one, haha.

Comment: <br /> would also work. The problem was the backslash -- should be a front slash